# Loading a h5 file into pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I just want to load a .h5 file exported from PyTorch, back into PyTorch.

Here's my code:

```py
import torch
loaded_model = torch.load('/Users/me/tmp_model.h5')
```

Which spits out the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bfb05a2f6d1e> in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 loaded_model = torch.load('/Users/arielelkin/tmp_model.h5')

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    605                     opened_file.seek(orig_position)
    606                     return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
--> 607                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    608         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    609 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, **pickle_load_args)
    880     unpickler = UnpicklerWrapper(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
    881     unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
--> 882     result = unpickler.load()
    883 
    884     torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in find_class(self, mod_name, name)
    873         def find_class(self, mod_name, name):
    874             mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
--> 875             return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
    876 
    877     # Load the data (which may in turn use `persistent_load` to load tensors)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

I know that the model was exported thus:

```py
ckpoint = 'version_131/epoch=171-step=1375.ckpt'
model = NSNetModel.load_from_checkpoint(Path('/Users/dev/Documents/models/'+ckpoint))
torch.save(model, 'tmp_model.h5')
```

What's the issue here? Am I missing an `import`?

Comment: how was this model exported? do you have the python code of the network?

Comment: @Shai I don't have the python code of the network, but I added the code used to export it.